# Add additinal functionality to existing methods

Tags: java, servlets, aop, decorator

I have a web application in Servlets and JSP. Now i need to add some additional  functionalities to a couple of service methods in it. Service methods those needs these changes are from different servlets.

Additional functionalities are as follows.

1. Validating status before its core function.
2. Notify respective users on successful completion of that process.

How can I inject these functionalities to existing code with minimum overhead? 
I think AOP in spring can help here, but i cant use Spring in existing application for this feature.

Also tried to use decorator pattern, but i couldn't as each service class contains multiple methods, also there is no common interface for them.

Can someone let me know how to handle this change in a better way.

Comment: If you can't use Spring and it's just a plain Servlet project, maybe you can write a Filter? You can set these up in your web.xml and it means you get a chance to have some code run around each request. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Answer (score 0):

> Also tried to use decorator pattern, but i couldn't as each service
>   class contains multiple methods, also there is no common interface for
>   them.

As you are stating that there is **no common interface**, **you can use Adapter Pattern** which is the best fit when you have problems with service interfaces. Basically, adapters help to interact with two services with no common interface. You can create an adapter (layer) which handle the additional functionalities (i.e., Validating status and Notify respective users, etc..) by invoking the existing services.

Below is the wikipedia definition for **adapter pattern**:

> the adapter pattern is a software design pattern (also known as
>   Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Decorator pattern) that
>   allows the interface of an existing class to be used as another
>   interface. It is often used to make existing classes work with others
>   without modifying their source code.